# consulta preparada en php no funciona (no da error)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy intentando ejecutar esta consulta pero no me da ningún error pero no me funciona, simplemente no ordena nada:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM productos ORDER BY :orden';
$stmt = $this->BD->prepare($sql);
$params = array(':orden'=>'titulo');
$stmt->execute($params);
return $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Prueba tu sentencia sql en phpmyadmin o cualquier administrador de bases de datos que utilices. 

Si los ordena correctamente así, es tu código. Sino, es tu sentencia.

Answer (score 2):

Los identificadores y los operadores, **no admiten** las capacidades de las consultas preparadas. Estos elementos han de existir en la consulta original. Imagínate si no el siguiente caso:

```
$sql = ":a :b :c :d";
$params = array(':a'=>'SELECT',':b'=>'*',':c'=>'FROM',':d'=>'productos');
$stmt = $this->BD->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

O, ya puestos:

```
$sql = ":a";
$params = array(':a'=>'SELECT * FROM productos');
$stmt = $this->BD->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

Como deseas que el orden pueda modificarse según conveniencia puedes hacer uso de las variables de PHP para que la consulta original tenga sus identificadores debidamente indicados:

```
$orden = 'titulo';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM productos ORDER BY $orden";
$stmt = $this->BD->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
return $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

Bastaria con

```
$orden = 'titulo';
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM productos ORDER BY $orden';
```